# How to trigger click of button that is hidden and has a codebehind event from clientside?

Tags: c#, jquery, onclick

I know how to trigger a button click via jquery. :

```
$('#hiddenSendButton').trigger('click');
```

What I was trying to do is have this trigger a click event in the codebehind.

```
<input id="hiddenSendButton" class="hiddenSendButton" type="hidden" runat="server" onclick="btnSend_Click" />
```

I don't think that I am doing this correctly, I am guessing that I need to use an asp.net button control in order to tie it to the codebehind, or something of that nature.

Here is my codebehind. :

```
Protected Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

I tried added in a handles clause but due to it being an input button it didn't have that.

Any ideas?  I am sure it is simple I just can't seem to find anything on this through my searching.

One of the things that I was thinking was using an asp.net button but how do I make that hidden but still visible on the clientside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will need to use an asp.net button control to tie it to the click event in the code-behind.

```
<asp:button runat="server" id="btnSend" class="hiddenSendButton" onclick="btnSend_Click" />
```

Also, in your example you have it as a hidden field, not a hidden button.  These are two very different things.  Hidden fields don't have the ability to be "clicked".

Comment: How do you go about hidding that asp.net button.  Via css?

Comment: Yeah, you could probably do a `style="display:none"`